# jQuery Split dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Help needed to split the dropdown value and put them to the inputs in two different tables.

```
$(document).on('change', '[id^="SelID_"]', function () {
SplitSelectValue($(this));
});

function SplitSelectValue(obj) {
    var data = obj.find("option:selected").val();
    var arr = data.split('|');
    var tr = obj.closest('tr');
    tr.find("[id^='SelVala_']").val(arr[0]);
    tr.find("[id^='SelValb_']").val(arr[1]);
    tr.find("[id^='SelValc_']").val(arr[2]);
    tr.find("[id^='SelVald_']").val(arr[3]);
    tr.find("[id^='SelVale_']").val(arr[4]);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/3744/)

Comment: values 4 and 5 can't be added to your `tr` object, as that one represents the `<tr>` in the first table, not in the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your function like this:

```
function SplitSelectValue(obj) {
    var data = obj.val();
    var arr = data.split('|');
    var tr = obj.closest('tr');
    tr.find(".SelVala_").val(arr[0]);
    tr.find(".SelValb_").val(arr[1]);
    tr.find(".SelValc_").val(arr[2]);

    var table2 = $('#AddFieldsToDebugDiv');
    var row = table2.find('tr:eq(' + tr.index() + ')');
    row.find(".SelVald_").val(arr[3]);
    row.find(".SelVale_").val(arr[4]);
}
```

Values `SelVald_` and `SelVale_` go to corresponding row of the second table. Also I changed ids to classes because id cannot be duplicated.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BE5Lr/3745/

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing tr.find with $

```
function SplitSelectValue(obj) {
    var data = obj.find("option:selected").val();
    var arr = data.split('|');
    //var tr = obj.closest('tr');
    $("[id^='SelVala_']").val(arr[0]);
    $("[id^='SelValb_']").val(arr[1]);
    $("[id^='SelValc_']").val(arr[2]);
    $("[id^='SelVald_']").val(arr[3]);
    $("[id^='SelVale_']").val(arr[4]);
}
```

Gave me the expected results

Comment: Your answer is close to workable solution, but I need to use "per row" value. Solution from **dfsq** works better. Thanks anyway.